# Google app engine: how to use downloaded data using the development server?

Tags: google-app-engine

After I download the data from my google app engine application I would like to start up the development server and see the downloaded data on the local pages.  Can I do this?  I'm sure I can, but I can't figure it out.  Sorry if this is a repeat or I'm just being stupid again.  Thanks in advance.  I'm using the Python environment, if that matters.

I tried this:

```
google_appengine/appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8080/ --filename=Data/copy.csv appname
```

and got this

```
Application: appname; version: 1.
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110201.103838
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20110201.103838.sql3
Please enter login credentials for localhost
Email: aaron.watters@google.com
Password for aaron.watters@google.com: 
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

what am I supposed to use to make authentication succeed?

Comment: should this @gmail.com instead of @google.com: aaron.watters@google.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[EDIT]:** Suddenly I saw a mistake in your command arguments. The URL should point to the `remote_api` path (i.e. `--url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api`).

Previous answer:

You cannot use the Google credentials you use for your live environment, as your local machine does not have a copy of the Google user db ;-)

There are two options for dealing with local authentication:

- No authentication

  Just comment out the login requirement for the remote API in your app.yaml file:

  ```
  - url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  #login: admin
  ```

  But this is not recommended as you might forget about turning it back on before you deploy.
- Create a local admin account

  Go to `http://localhost:8080/remote_api`.

  Login with any email address you like and make sure you tick the "Login as admin" checkbox.

  Now start the bulkloader script as before and when asked for a login, use the email address entered before. It should not ask you for a password.

Comment: This is weird, I cannot remember that I ever created such an admin account, but restore works locally. On a friend's computer it doesn't -- though we haven't tried creating an admin account locally.

Comment: I think I followed both procedures and neither worked for me.  In both cases I'm asked for a username and password and the autthentication fails.

Comment: @Aaron: I think there is a mistake in your command arguments. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, tomlog.  That worked, but I got disturbing message about a broken pipe Error in Thread-5: <urlopen error (32, 'Broken pipe')> -- hmmm.  However, it seemed to work.

Comment: [I think the broken pipe may have been related to having two processes listening on the same socket accidentally]

Comment: For me the missing link was to remote api was: http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api - slightly different /using builtins in my app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when you use the Federated Login authentication method. Change it back to Google User API and re-try. It will work ;)